# Остановка одного видео при проигрывании другого

Tags: javascript, html5

Можно ли программно управлять элементом  в HTML5? Как остановить проигрываемое на странице видео, если пользователь начал просмотр второго видео на этой же странице?

Comment: `HTMLMediaElement.play()` + `HTMLMediaElement.pause()`

Comment: HTMLMediaElrment2.onplaying = function(){HTMLMediaElement1.pause()};

Answer (score 0):

Предложу решение которое бы использовал я.

**Вариант #1 чистый JavaScript:**

```js
//Перебираем в цикле и останаливливаем все видео
for(var v of document.getElementsByTagName('video')){
 v.pause();
}
//Тут далее включаем PLAY нужного  видео
```

**Вариант 2 JQuery:**

```html
$('video').trigger('pause');
//Тут далее включаем PLAY нужного  видео
```

В обоих вариантах останавливаются на паузу все теги `video`, если нужно останавливать конкретнее можно использовать дополнительные идентификаторы вроде `ID` или `CLASS`

Comment: Хотел сделать пример с каким нибудь видео, но не нашел ссылок прямых ссылок на файлы видео

Comment: А на какое событие вешать обработчик?

Comment: не понял, код выполнять до вызова play для видео элемента, можете дополнить кодом и помогу конкретно с ним